# GKScore ReportScores method in C# example

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Can someone show me an example of how to write ReportScores example using C#? I've found many examples of how it is written in objective-C but not in C# and converters are pricy.
I've been using the old, deprecated now, GKScore ReportScore, and trying to move to the new GKScore ReportScores. I'm struggling at the Action parameter of the ReportScores method. Here is my code:

```
GKScore scoreReporter = new GKScore (category);
scoreReporter.Value = score;
GKScore[] allScores = new GKScore[] { scoreReporter };
scoreReporter.ReportScores(allScores, new Action<NSError> ((error) => {
```

it errs when it compiles at the last line saying:

```
Error CS0176: Static member `MonoTouch.GameKit.GKScore.ReportScores 
(MonoTouch.GameKit.GKScore[], System.Action 
<MonoTouch.Foundation.NSError>)' 
cannot be accessed with an instance reference, 
qualify it with a type name instead
```

and if I try to precede it with this line first:

```
Action<NSError> completionHandler = new Action<NSError> ();
scoreReporter.ReportScores(allScores, completionHandler
```

it errs at the top line saying:

```
method name expected
```

and if I try to remove the 'new' from "new Action()", it errs saying:

> *Error CS0119: Expression denotes a `type', where a`variable', `value' or`method group' was expected*

How should I write it in C#!?

Thanks

Comment: I deserve to know why I was getting -1 point... this is common courtesy to help each other improve. No comment is unprofessionalism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never mind, I found the answer. I ended up doing this:

```
GKScore scoreReporter = new GKScore (category);
scoreReporter.Value = score;
GKScore[] allScores = new GKScore[] { scoreReporter };
GKScore.ReportScores(allScores, (x) => {
    if(x == null){
        new UIAlertView ("Score reported", "Score Reported successfully", null, "OK", null).Show ();
    }
    else{
        new UIAlertView ("Score Reported Failed", "Score Reported Failed", null, "OK", null).Show ();
    }
    NSThread.SleepFor(1);
});
```